# I want to use this T-SQL syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried to construct this t-sql

```
SELECT
   dp.cod1,
   (select codruta from terce where terce.codcli = dp.codcli) as ruta,
   (select rutasec from terce where terce.codcli = dp.codcli) as rutasec,
   dp.bols,
   (select sum(cantidad) from diar where diar.id1diar = dp.id1) as cant,
   dp.nors
FROM 
   diariop as dp
ORDER BY 
   cod1, ruta, rutasec
```

Additionally, I need to include in `SELECT` a calculated column with : cant/25

I appreciate your collaboration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having subqueries in your SELECT clause, you should join your tables properly in your FROM clause. This will help your DB properly optomize your query and will make it much more efficient to select more than one column from a joined table as you are doing here with your `terce` table:

```
Select 
 dp.cod1,
 terce.codruta as ruta,
 terce.rutasec as rutasec,
 dp.bols,
 diarDT.sumOfCantidad as cant,
 diarDT.sumOfCantidad/25 as cant_divided_by_25,
 dp.nors
 FROM 
    diariop as dp
    LEFT OUTER JOIN terce ON
        terce.codcli = dp.codcli
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (select id1diar, sum(cantidad) as sumOfCantidad from diar GROUP BY id1diar ) as diarDT
        diarDT.id1diar=dp.id1
 ORDER BY cod1, ruta, rutasec
```

I'm still creating a derived table for your `diar` selection since you are summing in there and that is a good efficient way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks JNevill , but there is and error on : diar.id1diar=dp.id1

Comment: My apologies. I should have referenced the derived table `diarDT` not the actual table in the subquery `diar`. I have updated the SQL.

Answer (score -1):

If i've understood your question correctly, you could try with the following SQL

```
Select 
 dp.cod1,
 (select codruta from terce where terce.codcli = dp.codcli) as ruta,
 (select rutasec from terce where terce.codcli = dp.codcli) as rutasec,
 dp.bols,
 (select sum(cantidad) from diar where diar.id1diar=dp.id1) as cant,
 (select sum(cantidad) from diar where diar.id1diar=dp.id1)/25 as cantcalculated,
 dp.nors
 FROM diariop as dp
 ORDER BY cod1, ruta, rutasec
```

Comment: DO not use this answer. YOu shoudl not be writing correlated subqueries for this. They are performance killers and you shoudl never use them in production code.

Comment: Thanks HLGEM, I am using answer from JNevill.